# Using the definitive module pattern (DMP), how do I reference my observable property?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, this

I am using a service to make calling a dialog overlay available everywhere in my project. I have reduced the code only to the relevant parts.

When I call

```
userDialogService.hide()
```

from the console, it works just as expected.

**But when I call it from the view's click binding**, it says

**`isShown is not a function`**

which occurs in `userDialogService.hide()`:

```
this.isShown({ visible: false });
```

So probably my `this` gets screwed up. How do I fix it?

This is my service's (reduced) code:

```
var userDialogService = (function () {
    "use strict";
    var _private = {
        //BEGIN Private methods
        //END Private methods
    };

    var _public = {
        //BEGIN Public properties
        isShown: ko.observable({ visible: false }),
        //END Public properties
        //BEGIN Public methods
        show: function () {
            this.isShown({ visible: true });
        },
        hide: function () {
            this.isShown({ visible: false });
        },
        //END Public methods
    };
    
    return _public;
}).call(this);
```

So how do I refer to `isShown` properly in my `show()` and `hide()` methods? Will I have to prefix it with `_public.`? If so, why?

### Update:

This is the button with the click binding that calls `userDialogService.hide()`:

```
<button type="button" data-bind="click: userDialogService.hide">Close</button>
```

Comment: Can you produce a snippet that will demonstrate the error? The real cause is `hide` being called without its context.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/memosobumi/edit?js,console,output Strange enough, it works in the bin, yet it doesn't work in my project. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the following:

```
 var _public = {
    //BEGIN Public properties
    isShown: ko.observable({ visible: false }),
    //END Public properties
    //BEGIN Public methods
    show: function () {
        _public.isShown({ visible: true });
    },
    hide: function () {
        _public.isShown({ visible: false });
    },
    //END Public methods
};
```

this code ensures that the reference to the `_public` variable is retained even if the method would execute on another execution context.

**OPTION 2:**

You can also opt to use the apply invocation pattern on the code that wants to execute the `hide` and `show` methods of the service code.

**EX:**

```
userDialogService.hide.apply(userDialogService, *args here*);
```

***NOTE:*** if this script would be minified, this syntax would beat the use of `this` in terms of file size. ;)

Comment: Is this the only way?

Comment: @connexo, you can also use the apply syntax on the code that refers to your service code bro!

Comment: That is what the project is historically scattered with since they started when Knockout didn't have components yet. And that is what I'm trying to get rid of...

Comment: @connexo, I would personally pick the first option I provided because it is much smaller when minified and it is also more readable for development purposes.

Comment: After fiddling around with all the options offered, this is what I went with. Works as intended now, regardless of whether it is passed as a reference (e.g. to a click binding) or called from a different viewmodel function.

Answer (score 1):

As for the "why": when you use `this` in a function definition, you are saying it should be possible to call the function in various contexts. Sometimes that is useful. If it is not, you should provide the correct specific context, rather than `this`.

However, as long as you call it as a method call on `userDialogService`, it has the appropriate context. The error suggests that the function has been assigned or passed rather than called.

Comment: Actually, the problem comes from an element with a click binding: `<button type="button" data-bind="click: userDialogService.hide">Close</button>`.

Comment: Yes, you are passing the function to the binding handler. You can use `.bind()` on it or wrap it in a function (either anonymous or in your viewmodel) if you want to keep `this`

Comment: Would `onclick="userDialogService.hide()"` have the same issue?

Comment: No, it would have a different issue :). The `onclick` binding takes a function, not a code snippet. This is a common gotcha.

Comment: So it would have to be `onclick="userDialogService.hide"` and thus, also be passing a reference that has the same problem as the knockout click binding?

Comment: Right. `onclick:userDialogService.hide.bind(userDialogService)` is the workaround. Or have a viewmodel-level function `hideDialogService` that makes the call.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I had to pick one answer and I did so picking the one that has the code in it which I am now using.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
var _public = {}; //Make sure the object is available before
                  //we define the show and hide methods so
                  //it can be passed in the calls to bind

_public.isShown = ko.observable({ visible: false });

_public.show = function () {
        this.isShown({ visible: true });
}.bind(_public);

_public.hide = function () {
        this.isShown({ visible: false });
}.bind(_public);
```

From the documents linked above:

> **The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value**, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Comment: Is `bind()` available in ES3 (IE8 is relevant on this project)?

Comment: I just checked and sadly, `bind()` came with ES 5.1 and thus, is not available in IE8. So I cannot go with this solution.

Comment: @connexo You can easily polyfill the `bind` function, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too when I tried to find out which ES it is. But I'm unsure if that will have any unwanted implications on the project as it is quite a large project with hundreds of viewmodels.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I had to pick one answer and I did so picking the one that has the code in it which I am now using.

Comment: @connexo No problems.  Personally, I think the approach using `bind` is a bit ugly in this scenario, and it makes more sense to just use `_public` directly as per your accepted answer.

Comment: @connexo Although... I've just thought of yet another approach involving a private `isShown` observable and a public `isShown` writable computed.... Probably overkill though :)

Comment: Actually, ***that*** sounds ugly ;). In contrast to your feelings, I'd have loved to go with `bind()` as I feel it has been introduced specifically for scenarios like the above. But unluckily, our project will run only on two types of target devices, one of them incorporating IE8 on a cash machine.

Comment: @connexo Nice.  Yeah I guess you do want to know that it will work completely then!  I guess I'm also not surprised to learn that cash machines run IE8...